# Chisel3: How to create a register without reset signal in RawModule?

Tags: chisel

I want to create a RegNext in a RawModule, with the help of withClock. However, it can't work while the error information shows that missing implicit reset. So I have to  write it like this:

```
class Test extends RawModule {
  ...
  val nothing = Wire(Bool())
  nothing := DontCare
  val a = withClockAndReset(io.ui_clk, nothing) {
    RegNext(~io.in)
  }
  ...
}
```

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten it a little bit by using

```
withClockAndReset(io.ui_clk, false.B)
```

but I can't figure out a way to do it otherwise. `withClock` uses `withClockAndReset` internally and that's what cases the error. Maybe someone else has a better answer.

Comment: This is a bug, you should be able to do it without an implicit reset. Just to note, `RegNext` with a single argument (eg. `RegNext(~io.in)`, as above) does **not** have a reset, no matter what the implicit reset is.

Comment: I agree @jkoenig, I will submit an issue

Comment: I have create a bug report as chisel3 issue 1041